# Iniciar app com imagem do tipo splash screen

Tags: android

Quero que quando minha aplicação fosse iniciada, aparecesse uma imagem e depois abrisse o aplicativo em si. Semelhante o aplicativo YouTube que ao iniciar, aparece uma imagem do símbolo do YouTube e depois abre o app.

Comment: Procura sobre Splash screen que voce vai encontrar o que precisa.

Answer (score 6):

Esse recurso que você procura se chama `SplashScreen`.

Primeiro, crie um layout com a imagem que você gostaria que aparecesse no início. (Lembrando que ela deve estar na pasta Drawable)

Você terá algo do tipo:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
   android:layout_width="match_parent"  
   android:layout_height="match_parent"  
   android:orientation="vertical" >  

   <ImageView  
     android:id="@+id/imageView1"  
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:src="@drawable/imagem_splash" />  

 </LinearLayout>
```

Agora, você deve criar uma classe para podermos definir o tempo que esse layout irá ficar em execução.

Observe no exemplo abaixo, que definimos um `int` com o tempo que a tela irá ficar aberta. Depois disso, temos o método `run` onde definimos qual será a Activity chamada após o término do tempo que você definiu anteriormente.

```
 import android.app.Activity;  
 import android.content.Intent;  
 import android.os.Bundle;  
 import android.os.Handler;  

 public class SplashScreen extends Activity {  

   //Define tempo que a tela vai exibir. (tempo em milisegundos)
   private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;  

   @Override  
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
     setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);  

     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {  

       @Override  
       public void run() {  
            //Método que será executado uma vez.. Na abertura do app.  
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);  
         startActivity(i);  

         finish();  
       }  
     }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);  
   }  
 }
```

Por fim, não podemos esquecer de ir no `AndroidManifest.xml` e criarmos nossa nova Activity (a de Splash) lá.
Você terá algo como:

```
<activity  
       android:name="br.com.splashscreen.SplashScreen"  
       android:label="@string/app_name"  >
       <intent-filter>  
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />  
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />  
       </intent-filter>  
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

// tempo
private long splashRetraso = 2000;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tlsplah);
```

//código que faz oque vc quer

```
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent NovoLaytout;
            NovoLaytout = new Intent(Tlsplah.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(NovoLaytout);

            Tlsplah.this.finish();


        }
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task,splashRetraso);

}
```

}